# How to check which values are missing in datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, nan

I have a question about my dataset. I want to check which date + time is missing in my dataframe (see image). [DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xvj4.png) I want to know this for the columns named 'starttime' and 'endtime'.

How can I solve this?

I tried

```
pd.date_range(start = '2019-01-01 00:00:00', end = '2022-12-31 23:00:00' ).difference(allmerged.index)
```

but this is not working.

Trying the suggested code in the comments results in this output:
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9uVQ.png)

Comment: Please [do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Add a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)) instead.

Answer (score 0):

First there is frequency `15Min` in sample data, if need test this frequancy add parameter `freq` to [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html):

```
r = pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01 00:00:00', end='2022-12-31 23:00:00', freq='15Min')
```

If necessary convert both columns to datetimes:

```
df[['starttime','endtime']] = df[['starttime','endtime']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Last testing by [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
#testing both together
out = r.difference(np.ravel(df[['starttime','endtime']].to_numpy()))

out = r.difference(df[['starttime','endtime']].stack())

#testing separately
start = r.difference(df['starttime'])
end = r.difference(df['endtime'])
```

Comment: Thanks! My data is indeed al converted to datetime. However, when I do the separate testing, I get two strange values. Namely: ['2022-12-31T23:00:00.000000000']
['2019-01-01T00:00:00.000000000']. I will add a picture of this value to my question.

Comment: @J1999 - I change solution with `Index.difference`

Comment: With Index.difference, this is my output: DatetimeIndex(['2022-12-31 23:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None). Does that mean that there are no missing values?

Comment: @J1999 - I think you are correct.